# How can I add `quantities.Quantity`-behavior without subclassing it by using `__array__`?

Tags: python, numpy, units-of-measurement

`quantities.Quantity` is a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` that handles arithmetic and conversions of physical quantities. How can I make use of it's arithmetics without subclassing it? The following approach uses an `__array__`-method -- but just works 80%, as you can see in the end:

```
class Numeric(object):
  def __init__(self, signal):
    self.signal = signal
    self._dimensionality = self.signal._dimensionality
    self.dimensionality = self.signal.dimensionality
  def __array__(self):
    return self.signal
  def __mul__(self, obj):
    return self.signal.__mul__(obj)
  def __rmul__(self, obj):
    return self.signal.__rmul__(obj)
```

With this I can do:

```
import quantities as pq
import numpy as np

num = Numeric(pq.Quantity([1,2,3], 'mV'))
q = pq.Quantity([2,3,4], 'mV')
n = np.array([3,4,5])
```

All of the following operations return the correct unit -- **except the last, there the unit is missing**:

```
print num * num
# [1 4 9] mV**2
print num * q
# [ 2  6 12] mV**2
print num * n
# [ 3  8 15] mV
print q * num
# [ 2  6 12] mV**2
print n * num
# [ 3  8 15] <------- no unit!
```

Any idea, what to fix in order to keep the correct unit?

**edit**: The return type/value of an arithmentic opperation should be equivalent to:

- `num.signal * num.signal`
- `num.signal * q`
- `num.signal * n`
- `q * num.signal`
- `n * num.signal # this doesn't work`

Comment: If you are looking for a Python units package with great NumPy support but without requiring NumPy to work, take a look at http://pint.readthedocs.org/ (Disclaimer: I am one of the authors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Python sees `x * y` here's what happens:

- if `y` is a subclass of `x` --> `y.__rmul__(x)` is called

otherwise:

- `x.__mul__(y)` is called

**IF** `x.__mul__(y)` returns `NotImplemented` (which is different from `raise NotImplementedError`

- `y.__rmul__(x)` is called

So, there are two ways that `__rmul__` can be called -- subclass `ndarray`, or have `ndarray` not be able to multiply with `Numeric`.

You are unable to subclass, and apparently `ndarray` is happy to work with `Numeric`, so **. . .**

Thankfully, the `numpy` folks prepared for situations such as this -- the answer lies in the `__array_wrap__` method:

```
def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
    return type(self.signal)(out_arr, self.dimensionality)
```

We are using the original `signal` class, along with the original dimensionality, to create a new signal for the new `Numeric` object.

The entire bit looks like this:

```
import quantities as pq
import numpy as np

class Numeric(object):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.signal = signal
        self.dimensionality = self.signal.dimensionality
        self._dimensionality = self.signal._dimensionality
    def __array__(self):
        return self.signal
    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        return type(self.signal)(out_arr, self.dimensionality)
    def __mul__(self, obj):
        return self.signal.__mul__(obj)
    def __rmul__(self, obj):
        return self.signal.__rmul__(obj)


num = Numeric(pq.Quantity([1,2,3], 'mV'))
q = pq.Quantity([2,3,4], 'mV')
n = np.array([3,4,5])

t = num * num
print type(t), t
t = num * q
print type(t), t
t = num * n
print type(t), t
t = q * num
print type(t), t
t = n * num
print type(t), t
```

And when run:

```
<class 'quantities.quantity.Quantity'> [1 4 9] mV**2
<class 'quantities.quantity.Quantity'> [ 2  6 12] mV**2
<class 'quantities.quantity.Quantity'> [ 3  8 15] mV
<class 'quantities.quantity.Quantity'> [ 2  6 12] mV**2
<class 'quantities.quantity.Quantity'> [ 3  8 15] mV
```

Comment: Excellent answer! One question to numpy behaviour: `n * num` uses `num.__array__` for calculation (check with `print "in __array__"` within that method). BUT: `n * num.__array__()` provides the unit, `n * num` does not. Isn't that a bug in numpy (or at least very unintuative/unexpected)?

Comment: @PhilippderRautenberg: No. The `__array__` method is simply returning `self.signal` which is a `Quantity` object, and `Quantity` ojbects know about units, while `ndarray` does not.

Comment: @PhilippderRautenberg what you're asking for is kind of strange. You want numpy to do <ndarray> * <Numeric> and return <quantities.quantity.Quantity>. It would probably make more sense if `__array__` returned an ndarray, not a Quantity and `__array_wrap__` returned a Numberic, not a Quantity. In fact, have considered sub-classing Quantity?

Comment: @Bago: For reasons of controling numerical values, e.g. for caching and database access, I would like to have a class `Numeric` that stores the numerical value within an attribute like `signal`. Behavior should reflect behavior of the `signal`: `<ndarray> * <Numeric>` should do the same like `<ndarray> * <Numeric>.signal`. Therefore, the return type does not have to be `<quantities.Quantity>`. Anyhow, that should be the return type of the example with a <quantities.Quantity> as `signal`.

Comment: @EthanFurman: if `<Numeric.signal>` has type `<Quantity>` then (even without the `__array_wrap__`): __(1)__ `<ndarray> * <Numeric.signal>` => `<Quantity>`; __(2)__ `<ndarray> * <Numeric.__array__()>` => `<Quantity>`. That works already fine! BUT: __(3)__ `<ndarray> * <Numeric>` => `<ndarray>` although that leads to the same calculation as __(2)__.

Comment: @PhilippderRautenberg `ndarray * Numeric` is roughly `Numeric.__array_wrap__(numpy.asarray(Numeric) * ndarray)` notice that `numpy.asarray(Numeric)` or `numpy.asarray(Quantity)` both return an ndarray. The reason that `Numeric * ndarray` works is because it calls your `__mul__` function which does `num.signal * ndarray` (and `num.signal` does have a `__array_wrap__`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to definine `__array_wrap__`.  See [the documentation here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs).

As a quick example using your example (but not requiring `quantities`):

```
class Numeric(object):
  def __init__(self, signal):
    self.signal = signal
  def __array__(self):
    return self.signal
  def __mul__(self, obj):
    return type(self)(self.signal.__mul__(obj))
  def __rmul__(self, obj):
    return type(self)(self.signal.__rmul__(obj))

import numpy as np

num = Numeric(np.arange(10))
n = np.arange(10)

print type(num * n)
print type(n * num)
```

This yields:

```
<class '__main__.Numeric'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If we include `__array_wrap__`:

```
class Numeric(object):
  def __init__(self, signal):
    self.signal = signal
  def __array__(self):
    return self.signal
  def __mul__(self, obj):
    return type(self)(self.signal.__mul__(obj))
  def __rmul__(self, obj):
    return type(self)(self.signal.__rmul__(obj))
  def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
    return type(self)(out_arr)

import numpy as np

num = Numeric(np.arange(10))
n = np.arange(10)

print type(num * n)
print type(n * num)
```

It yields:

```
<class '__main__.Numeric'>
<class '__main__.Numeric'>
```

However, I'm still confused as to why you can't just subclass `ndarray` in the first place... I suspect it would be a lot cleaner in the long run.  If you can't, you can't, though.

To fully mimic an `ndarray` without subclassing `ndarray`, you're going to need to get very familiar with [the details of subclassing them](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Comment: I need to write a little package for a community that needs to operate on `Quantity`. Additonally, I need a fallback-solution to `ndarray` to stay independent of `quantities` in order to provide a debian package (`quantities` is not packaged, yet). This is one of some more reasons (e.g. SQLAlchemy-Mapping) why I would like to encapsulate the numeric part into the `signal`-attribut.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `__array_wrap__`. The unit-problem remains, though. For some reason `__rmul__` is not called for `n * num`. Maybe that is a `numpy`-bug?

Comment: Also the return type sould be the same like `n * num.signal`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the python reference,](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) `__rmul__` of the right operand is "only called *if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation* and the operands are of different types."

So the problem is that when you run `n * num.signal`, `numpy.array` does support the multiplication and takes over. The only way I see around that would be if there's a way to make `Numeric` incompatible with `numpy.array.__mul__`